# Await a long-lived Task to know it started without blocking

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task

I'm curious as to what the community feels (knows) is best practice regarding running long-lived background tasks (in my case an HTTP server).  Ideally, I'd like to be able to await the `Start` method, but don't want it to block further execution.

It seems I have two options: 1) await (and nothing after that statement executes), or 2) assign the Task to a variable in the consuming code.

1. Await (i.e. "Waiting for connections" never shows)

```
class Program
{
    static HttpListener _Listener = null;
    static string _ListenerPrefix = "http://localhost:8888/";
    static Task _AcceptConnectionsTask = null;

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        _Listener = new HttpListener();
        _Listener.Prefixes.Add(_ListenerPrefix);

        Console.WriteLine("Starting server on " + _ListenerPrefix);
        await Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for connections");
    }

    static Task Start()
    {
        _Listener.Start();
        _AcceptConnectionsTask = Task.Run(() => AcceptConnections());
        return _AcceptConnectionsTask;
    }

    static async Task AcceptConnections()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            HttpListenerContext ctx = await _Listener.GetContextAsync()
                .ConfigureAwait(false);
            await Task.Run(() => HandleConnection(ctx));
        }
    }

    static async void HandleConnection(HttpListenerContext ctx)
    {
        string ip = ctx.Request.RemoteEndPoint.Address.ToString();
        int port = ctx.Request.RemoteEndPoint.Port;
        Console.WriteLine("Request received from " + ip + ":" + port + " "
            + ctx.Request.HttpMethod + " " + ctx.Request.Url);
        
        // do stuff and respond...
    }
}
```

2. Assign to Task variable ("Waiting for connections" shows)

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    _Listener = new HttpListener();
    _Listener.Prefixes.Add(_ListenerPrefix);

    Console.WriteLine("Starting server on " + _ListenerPrefix);
    // await Start();
    Task t = Start();
    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for connections");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

My question is, is there a way to await so that I know the Task started without precluding the statements immediately following from executing?

Comment: `await Start()` doesn't block. It asynchronously waits for the task to finish without blocking.

Comment: Sorry, thanks for correcting me there.  What I meant was it precludes the ```Console.WriteLine("Waiting for connections");``` from executing.

Comment: Yes, that's because you are executing it once the awaited task has finished.

Comment: So is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Remove the calls to `Task.Run` and print the message to the console before calling `GetContextAsync()`? `Start()` is never meant to exit it seems.

Comment: As a side note the `HandleConnection` method in your example is `async void`, which is [something to avoid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void).

Comment: Thank you @TheodorZoulias, I was not aware!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing is that `await Start()` doesn't block. It asynchronously waits for the task to finish without blocking.

The "Waiting for connections" message should be printed to the console before the long-running task completes, for example right before you call `GetContextAsync()` to asynchronously wait for a request.

Also, you should remove the calls to `Task.Run` and let the program be "async all the way" without involving any background threads. Something like this:

```
class Program
{
    static HttpListener _Listener = null;
    static string _ListenerPrefix = "http://localhost:8888/";

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        _Listener = new HttpListener();
        _Listener.Prefixes.Add(_ListenerPrefix);

        Console.WriteLine("Starting server on " + _ListenerPrefix);
        await Start();
    }

    static async Task Start()
    {
        _Listener.Start();
        await AcceptConnections().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    static async Task AcceptConnections()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for connections");
        while (true)
        {
            HttpListenerContext ctx = await _Listener.GetContextAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            HandleConnection(ctx);
        }
    }

    static void HandleConnection(HttpListenerContext ctx)
    {
        string ip = ctx.Request.RemoteEndPoint.Address.ToString();
        int port = ctx.Request.RemoteEndPoint.Port;
        Console.WriteLine("Request received from " + ip + ":" + port + " " + ctx.Request.HttpMethod + " " + ctx.Request.Url);

        // do stuff and respond...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks; I didn't want to block AcceptConnections() from getting the next context by having HandleConnection run synchronously after it.

Comment: If I'm reading your answer correctly, with the while(true) loop in AcceptConnections, there isn't a way to await this without it waiting until the while(true) loop exits.  i.e. I could add another method in between Start and AcceptConnections that would start AcceptConnections in the background and return right away.  Correct?

Comment: @joelc: `AcceptConnections` will return (but not complete) when it hits `await _Listener.GetContextAsync()`. The remainder of the method will then be executed once you have received a request and the task returned from `GetContextAsync` completes.

Comment: Right, i.e. if HandleConnection() takes a long time, it won't be able to get the next request.

Comment: Right, `HandleConnection` is synchronous and meant to return fast in my example, Depending on what you are doing in it, you might want to offload the execution of it to another thread while listening for another request on the main thread.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer.  What's clear to me is that await will preclude the code from continuing until the while loop exits, and the only way to really do this is either not await and assign to a Task, or, have the awaited method start another background task upon which the method itself does not await.  I appreciate your insight, have a good one!

Answer (score 2):

What you probably want to do, is to separate the creation from the awaiting of the task:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    //...
    Console.WriteLine("Starting server on " + _ListenerPrefix);
    Task t = Start();
    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for connections (the task has been started)");
    await t;
    Console.WriteLine("The task has been completed");
}
```